# How can I make leftsidebar responsive into top navbar when resizing certain width

Tags: html, css

This is how my code looks like

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("leftsidebar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
  color: #000;
  font: 10pt/18pt Arial, sans-serif;
  border-top: 6px;
}

#navbar {
  max-width: 928px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4596d8;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 946px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background: #FFF;
}

#leftsidebar {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid #4596d8;
}

#leftsidebar ui a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid red rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#leftsidebar ui a:hover {
  background-color: #4596d8;
}

#maincontent {
  width: 728px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font: 10pt/18pt Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 6px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #4596d8;
}

form {
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-inline {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .leftsidebar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .leftsidebar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .leftsidebar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .leftsidebar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  #navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  MySite
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="leftsidebar">
    <ui>
      <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site1</a>
      <a href="site2.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site2</a>
      <a href="site3.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site3</a>
      <a href="site4.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site4/a>
            <a href="site5.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site5</a>
    </ui>
  </div>
```

When I resize my site everything stays the same, nothing changes. I changed the lines so many times and nothing changed. Besides this problem everything else I could solve on my own.

My code is from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) example. The only difference from the example site is, that my websites navbar is on the left and my logo in in the top navbar. So when I resize it or am on a certain width the menu elements are in the navbar hidden behind a icon.

Comment: Could you also add the css that is on the elements without the media query?

Comment: Done, sorry I should have known the entire css code is needed.

Comment: Hope this [tutorial](https://codyhouse.co/ds/components/app/responsive-sidebar) will help you!

Answer (score 1):

You where using the `.leftsidebar` selector (class selector) instead of `#leftsidebar` the ID selector. The element doesnt have a class so you have to use `#leftsidebar`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("leftsidebar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
  color: #000;
  font: 10pt/18pt Arial, sans-serif;
  border-top: 6px;
}

#navbar {
  max-width: 928px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4596d8;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 946px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  background: #FFF;
}

#leftsidebar {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid #4596d8;
}

#leftsidebar ui a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid red rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#leftsidebar ui a:hover {
  background-color: #4596d8;
}

#maincontent {
  width: 728px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font: 10pt/18pt Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 6px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #4596d8;
}

form {
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-inline {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #leftsidebar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  #leftsidebar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #leftsidebar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  #leftsidebar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  #navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  MySite
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="leftsidebar">
    <ui>
      <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site1</a>
      <a href="site2.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site2</a>
      <a href="site3.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site3</a>
      <a href="site4.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site4/a>
            <a href="site5.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Site5</a>
    </ui>
  </div>
```

Comment: Right. Indeed I see my mistakes now. But why is still site1 there if I resize it and the other menu links are entirely gone.

Comment: Because your css selector says it (a:not(:first-child)) if you remove the :not(:first-child) (and leave the a) it Will remove all a

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of bugs. Firstly the ui (unordered list) has to have li as it children. Anything besides an li as a ui child is a bug. Though you can have your link inside li you cannot have it as child of ui directly. If you put value 0 as border it doesn't work  and is a bug. You should value it as none instead of 0 so border: none; the same with background padding and outline it should have a value of none.
Margin cant be both 0 and auto just say auto instead of 0 auto. You should also see some  actual code of others. You are using code like english not like computer you have used a lot uneccesary css properties. Watch others coding youtube. You can use padding and margin the best way instead of writing padding left padding top. Just use thus syntax: padding: top right bottom left;
For example padding: 0 9px 0 9px;

For your media queries search on internet and use @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {} device that has 600 px width like a mobile

Dont use the same value use a different value.
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {} this implements on a 900px width device like tablet.

Comment: I know. First I wanted to build the site how I want it to look like and after that I would go for "bug hunting" and remove everything what is unnecessary.